# How to import SVG icons to Sketch so that they don't open each in different sketch files but all in one

Tags: svg, icon, sketch-app

Recently I got a problem, when I am importing Svg icons from one folder, they are automatically opened in separate sketch files, so I have 100 opened sketch files in total. Can someone help with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just drag them into an open file they should all appear in the current document- stacked on top of each other. You can then use the "make grid" function to spread them out.